# Can I declare method as toString with lombok annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Is it possible to declare a certain function `foo()` as toString ? Concretely:

```
int property 1;
int property 2;
int property 3;

boolean bar() {...}

int foo(){
  return bar() ? 0 : property2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.valueOf(foo());
}
```

Now I want to replace the toString() with a Lombok annotation. Which has the same output as the current one. is this somehow possible with Lombok?

Comment: just add @ToString on your class https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString

Comment: _Why_ do you want to replace it with an annotation?

Comment: You are not just using another function as `toString`, but processing the result (turning an `int` to `String`). I very much doubt that this is possible with an annotation. But of course you can still just override `toString` even if it is already generated with `@Data` or a similar Lombok annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of lombok is to 'write code for you' - if you've already written it, why would you want this?

What you can do is put a `@ToString.Include` annotation on your foo() method, which will cause lombok to list the result of invoking this method along with all the fields. If your method has the same name as one of your methods (or the same name after putting `get` in front and capitalizing the first letter), the method's output replaces that field. You can then put a marker on `@ToString` to say that you only want explicitly included stuff, at which point lombok's toString will emit something like: `"YourClass(foo=12)"`:

```
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded=true)
public class YourClass {
    int property1, property2, property3;

    @ToString.Include
    int foo() {
        return bar() ? 0 : property2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, I have no real reason to force myself to use lombok here to write any code for me because it is already written by me :D thanks !